# PHP, Функция экспоненциального распределения. Неоднозначность в документации

Tags: php, математика, документация, distribution

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stats-cdf-exponential.php

Описывается функция таким образом:

> Returns the cumulative distribution function, its inverse, or one of
>   its parameters, of the exponential distribution. The kind of the
>   return value and parameters (par1 and par2) are determined by which.

Вот про "one of its parameters" и "distribution function" все понятно и четко описано, как их получать.

А вот про `its inverse` вообще непонятно. Что это?

1. Обратная функция? Какой-то хитрый математический термин применимый к распределениям (гуглил - не нашел)?
2. Банальный косяк копипасты при написании документации?

Comment: Судя по таблице `Return value and parameters`, имеем следующий расклад. При `which == 1`, параметрами служат `x` и `lambda`, и функция возвращает `CDF`, т.е. `cumulative distribution function`. При `which == 2`, параметрами служат `CDF` и `lambda`, и функция возвращает `x`, т.е. `its inverse`. При `which == 3`, параметрами служат `x` и `CDF`, и функция возвращает `lambda`, т.е. `one of its parameters`.